# Another application breaks QTimer in thread on Windows with c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtimer

I have my own little framework (`serial_port` below) to send/get messages via QSerialPort. Here how I start it with another thread:

```
serial_port->moveToThread(connection_thread);
serial_port->serial->moveToThread(connection_thread);
serial_port->timer->moveToThread(connection_thread);
```

Then I connect signals:

```
connect(connection_thread, SIGNAL(started()), serial_port, SLOT(start_loop()));
connect(serial_port, SIGNAL(finished()), connection_thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(connection_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), serial_port, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(serial_port, SIGNAL(finished()), connection_thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

In the `serial_port` QTimer sends message with timeout:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(send_message()));
```

My problem that another program, running after `QTimer` starts working, is breaking this timer. It takes place somewhere about 20% cases. Issue consist of getting `timeout()` signal much more faster than it is supposed. It happens on Windows platform but everything is okay for Linux. Where could I find the issue's reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

- `connection_thread->setPriority(QThread::HighestPriority);`

or

- `connection_thread->setPriority(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);`

to make the scheduled more often.

***and***

- `serial_port->timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer)`

to make your `QTimer` a `PriciseTimer` type.

Hope it helps you.